# Toggling a DIV from a clickable list element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on what should be a simple function for a way too long now. I have a list of items. When each is clicked, I want it to toggle a hidden div with info on that item without using jQuery. I have copied almost line-for-line several examples from this site and others, and tried so many variations but nothing seems to be working. I'm hoping it is a simple solution but I'm driving myself crazy right now. Getting discouraged, any ideas?

**JS:**

```
var div = document.getElementById('show')
var beer = document.getElementById('beer')

function show_div() {
    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = ""
    } else {
        div.style.display = "none"
    }
};
```

**CSS**

```
div { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<li>Beers I Currently Have
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="beer" onclick="show_div">2 Sierra Nevada Bigfoot (12/11/14)</a></li>
    <div id="show">Delicious barley wine that has been aging in my cellar for nearly 2 years now.</div>
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="beer">2 Sierra Nevada Bigfoot (12/11/13)</a>
        <div hidden>Delicious barley wine that has been aging in my cellar for nearly 2 years now.</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* No need to set display:none here
   since we are using 'hidden' directly
   in the element. */
#beer div { }
```

JavaScript:

```
var beer = document.getElementById('beer')

// Add an event listener to beer. Listen for
// the 'click' event.
beer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default <a> behavior

    info = e.target.nextElementSibling;
    if (info.hidden) info.hidden = false;
    else info.hidden = true;

    return false; // prevent default <a> behavior
});
```

Basically, each list item consists of a link and a div. Users click on the link to toggle the div. Put them next to each other in the DOM so you can access the div easier. For example, now you can use e.target.nextElementSibling in order to access the next sibling element of the `<a>` element. If you are confused about what `e` is, put in a `console.log(e)` in that click handler to check it out.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zs6aL7x2/

Comment: I've tried similar solutions with addEventListener, and while they should work in theory and on sites like JSFiddle, this isn't working in my IDE (brackets). it's returning 'cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null'.

Comment: Put `console.log(beer)` before the `addEventListener` line to check what the `document.getElementById('beer')` call returned and paste it here.

Comment: `var beer = document.getElementById("beer")
   console.log(beer);` returned `null` on the console

Comment: Double check if there is a DOM element with id=beer... double check if the JavaScript file has been linked to the HTML file... try making a dummy element and checking if you can get its ID using JavaScript... try linking the JavaScript at the bottom of your HTML page to make sure the DOM is fully loaded before the JS executes... I don't know, just throwing some things out there.

Comment: oh wow it actually works when I move the javascript to the bottom of the HTML. That's frustrating that that's all it took in the end, but thanks for your help!

Comment: :D awesome, glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

- onclick="show_div" should be `onclick="show_div()"`

  - div { display: none; } shold be div #show{ display: auto; }
  - Remember to use `;` at the end of each statement

```js
var div = document.getElementById('show');
    var beer = document.getElementById('beer');

    function show_div() {
    if(div.style.display == "none"){
    div.style.display = "";
    } else { div.style.display = "none";
    }
    };
```

```css
#show { display: auto; }
```

```html
<li>Beers I Currently Have
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="beer" onclick="show_div()">2 Sierra Nevada Bigfoot (12/11/14)</a></li>
        <div id="show">Delicious barley wine that has been aging in my cellar for nearly 2 years now.</div>
```

**However I would do this using getComputedStyle function..because if you use div.style.display, it will find any inline display styling instead of css styling**

Here is another approcach using getComputedStyle function

```js
var div = document.getElementById('show');
    var beer = document.getElementById('beer');

    function show_div() {
    console.log(div.style.display);
    if(getComputedStyle(div,null).display== "none"){
    div.style.display = "block";
    } else { div.style.display = "none";
    }
    };
```

```css
#show { display: none; }
```

```html
<li>Beers I Currently Have
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="beer" onclick="show_div()">2 Sierra Nevada Bigfoot (12/11/14)</a></li>
        <div id="show">Delicious barley wine that has been aging in my cellar for nearly 2 years now.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, and I should've realized to add the () after the function. However, while both of your approaches work on this site, neither are working in my IDE. "Cannot read property style of null"

Comment: what environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Brackets